# Django. Models. Create same class another instance inside it's method

Tags: django, model

I have some Djanog application to work with text and save info in database.
And there is some cutom method like this:
`

```
class TextClass(models.Model):
    property1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='__')

    def meth1(self, text_lines):
       if condition1:
           self.property1 = some_info
           self.save()
```

Is it possible in case of another condition inside `meth1` to create one more instance of the same class to fill it's properties with info from text block?

Comment: So are you saying that you want to create an instance of `TextClass` based on the information from `text_lines`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access model from instance in several ways.

1. `type(instance)`
2. `instance.__class__`
3. `instance._meta.model`
4. etc...

I recommend first way. Or you can also get model to django builtin lazy method `apps.get_model('<app_name>.TextClass')` in `django.apps` module.

When you got model class in method, you could create another instance.